# Cannot catch MySQLdb.OperationalError on App Engine

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, mysql-python

I have a Django app running on Google App Engine. From time to time the DB raises `OperationalError` which is normal, however my code, although using try..except, is not catching the exception (I need this for retry purposes).

Here is my code:

```
from MySQLdb import OperationalError, DatabaseError

DB_RETRY_EXCEPTIONS = (
    OperationalError,
    DatabaseError,
)

class MyClassView(rest_framework.views.APIView):
    @retry(DB_RETRY_EXCEPTIONS, tries=5, delay=5, logger=logger)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(MyClassView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        except DB_RETRY_EXCEPTIONS as exp:
            logger.warning("Got %s", exp)
            raise
```

In the exception stack trace, I can see that the flow is going through this piece of code, but no warnings.

Here is the last lines of the stack trace:

```
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 190, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 38")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that there is another `OperationalError` at `django.db.utils.OperationalError` and that's was the one that was raised. The solution was to catch also this exception.